# CUDA code too large to be expanded

Tags: cuda, expansion

I have a very large code for a function that has to be called twice in a kernel.
The compiler gives me the error:

> Signal:caught in phase Code_Expansion -- processing aborted.

When I try to call the function only once I don't get this error!
How can I get around this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps see if you can get the compiler to not inline the function using [`__noinline__`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#noinline-and-forceinline)

Comment: It seems to work, but the compiler doesn't stop working so I canceled the build.

Comment: @RaduDragomir: What CUDA and host compiler versions are you talking about here?